# How to I get the right json-datatype for the autocomplete function?

Tags: jquery, json, perl, autocomplete, mojolicious

When I try this, it works as expected: after two characters its shows the matching entries.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="development-bundle/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            var data = [ 'John', 'Jack', 'Joe', 'Lisa', 'Barbara' ];
            $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" 
        id="name" name="name" /></td></tr>
    </table><br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This behaves different: after two characters it shows always all entries?
What is wrong with the second example?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use utf8;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/eingabe' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render( 'eingabe' );
};

get '/search_db' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render( json => [ 'John', 'Jack', 'Joe', 'Lisa', 'Barbara' ] );
};

app->start;

__DATA__
@@ eingabe.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="/development-bundle/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
                source: '/search_db',
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text"
        id="name" name="name" /></td></tr>
    </table><br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fix your question title. A list of technologies (we already have tags) followed by the word "question" does not describe your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you are using an array to set the options of the autocomplete.  In the second the array is being searilizied into json, however the autocomplete expects the json to have specific key/value pairs (id, label, and value).

I think your best bet would be to define a custom callback for the autocomplete's data as shown in [this tutorial from nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/).

Your autocomplete code would look something similar to this:

```
$("#name").autocomplete({
    source : function(req, add){ 
        $.getJSON("/search_db" + req, function(data){
            suggestions = [];

            len = data.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                suggestions.push(data[i]);
            };

            add(suggestions); //passing an array to add will populate the suggest list

        });//end getjson callback
    }
})
```

Comment: I changed my script this way, but I didn't get a different result.

Comment: Did you look at the tutorial?  I think it does a more complete job of explaining how to using the autocomplete with a remote datasource and custom callback.

Comment: Reading `When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. ... The request parameter "term" gets added to that URL. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.` and `... to pass the term to a server-side PHP file. The PHP file will use the term to extract matching contact names from a MySql database.` I suppose when the source is a URL it is supposed to behave different as with local data.

Comment: So with filtering on server side I can save traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I think nothing is wrong wrong with your example, it works perfectly.
But please make sure you are loading your JS from right path and that you are trying right url: http://127.0.0.1:3000/eingabe

I modified your example to load Google hosted libraries and it's just works:
https://gist.github.com/106e8c4eb7483333aa08

(at least in Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: When I enter `Jo` as the first two characters I don't want showing up the whole list, but only `John` and `Joe` (as it happens in the first example).