# JSON feed not populating source for autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, external

Noticed lots of people having this issue! not any of them seemed to help my problem though!

My JSON feed is http://menu.the-dot.co.uk/getingredients.php?func=json

I've got a fiddle setup at http://jsfiddle.net/OwenMelbz/xgQnQ/ with the code to test

```
$(function() {
$("#food").autocomplete({
    source: "http://menu.the-dot.co.uk/getingredients.php?func=json",
    minLength: 2,
    dataType: "json",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    }
});
});
```

this is literally copy and pasted from the demo page on jqueryui.com apart from dataType added and source added, as well as the selector changing!

Basically, you type in the box using this feed. Nothing comes up. you type in the box using source: myArray it works, anyone see my issue with the code and demos i've provided?

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the JSON output be an array, not an object?

Comment: have you seen this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365515/how-to-i-get-the-right-json-datatype-for-the-autocomplete-function

Comment: this is my first time touching json, so not sure what the difference is, the jquryui website documentation for remote sources was non-existent.

Comment: you can change `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "jsonp"` to overcome cross domain issue

Answer (score 0):

From where are you sending the request. Is it same as

> http://menu.the-dot.co.uk/

If it is not same, you will have [cross domain request](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) problem. Please check the response using chrome developer tool or firebug. See whether any error is coming or not.

Comment: Yep: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load *trimmed*. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` (For the fiddle posted)

Comment: its on the same domain, i just used the fiddle to show my code

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is malformed. Otherwise it works fine, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgQnQ/10/)

Comment: i ran it through a validator and it said it was fine. as far as im aware the updated fiddle isnt that a standard javascript array rather than a json object?

Comment: Yes, you need an array. You have made an "object" which under the most generous interpretation is renaming the same property (ingredient) again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Well I decided that I think the issue wasnt with any of the code, but how the php script that delivered the JSON wasnt acting how autocomplete would expect.

So instead i've created a javascript array version of my database which is now http://menu.the-dot.co.uk/getingredients.php?func=js

and included this script in the header of the page, so it loads the database content into a javascript array then i use autocomplete to read the array. Less requests from the server also. lovely jubbly.

http://menu.the-dot.co.uk/body.html?page=find

working perfectly :) its a ios webapp so excuse the nasty browser view :)